# Is this a valid URL ?& empty parameter

Tags: http, url

is something like

www.example.com?&hello=world

valid can you have ?& on valid URL, I tested on firefox, chrome, and safari, they seem to just remove the & between the ? and the h

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The part between `?` and `#` or the end of the URI is called “query”. According to the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) there are no restrictions on how the part actually may look like. So yes, it *is* a valid URI. The `key=value` format is just one possible (albeit the most common one) format for that place.

As for how servers or clients parsing that URL of yours behave, they will just ignore that empty section. So no, it’s not a problem, and you won’t run into issues because of that extraneous ampersand.